# Basic Java inheritance exercise

Tags: java, inheritance, hierarchy, multiple-inheritance

I'm learning Java and I'm doing this exercise and I have to say what the main method prints. Its goal is to better understand Java inheritance.

```
interface X extends Remote{
    A m(B bb) throws RemoteException;
}

class A implements Serializable{
     int a;
     A m(A aa){ 
         aa.a = 3; 
         System.out.println("A.m"); 
         return aa;
     }
}

class B extends A{
     int b;
     A m(B bb){
        bb.b = 7; 
        System.out.println("B.m");
        return bb;
     }
}

class C extends A implements X{
    public B m(B bb){
        if(bb.b == 7) bb.b = 9; else bb.b = 1;
        System.out.println("C.m");
        return bb;
    }
}
```

Now I have a main method in which I call:

```
X x = new C();
B b = new B();
(x.m(b)).m(b);   // prints C.m() A.m()
```

The third line of my main method, prints "C.m() A.m()" but I don't understand why it prints A.m(). The x.m(b) returns an object that has both static and dynamic type == B; on this object it is invoked m(b) method; so why it is not called the m() method of B class?

I've seen that the m() mehtod in B class is not an overriding of the m() method in A class because they have different explicit parameter.

thanks in advance

Comment: I would start from avoiding naming things as A,a,aa, m(A aa), a.m, aa.a. It just makes code harder to read.

Comment: You are right and I totally agree with you. It's an exercise taken from a book, it's only to explore inheritance. Any ideas about why it prints C.m() A.m() instead of C.m() B.m() as I supposed? Thanks m8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`b` in an instance of `B`, which extends `A`. As such, `B` has 2 `m` methods.

To know which is called, what is important is the type of the object on which the method is called.

```
(x.m(b))
```

is the result of the call to the `m` method from the `X` interface, because the declaring type of `x` is `X`.

Therefore `(x.m(b))` is an object of type `A` (even though the actual implementation is a `B`).

This being a type `A`, the `m` method from the `A` class is called.

If you change the names of the methods, it will become clearer that the `m` methods from `A` and `B` are really different objects.

Your mistake is assuming that

> The x.m(b) returns an object that has both static and dynamic type == B;

Which is wrong, because `x` is declared of type `X`, making the result of `x.m` a type `A`.

Comment: another important point is that the method in `B` `A m(B bb){` does not override the method in `A` `A m(A aa){` because the argument is more specific, meaning it cannot answer all calls of the method in `A`. (But I think you already understood that part).